# Automapper says Missing map from System.String to System.Char? But I see no Char property

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got three classes:

```
public class UserReport : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> Departments { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLastModified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    protected Entity()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        DateLastModified = DateTime.Now;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Departments { get; set; }
    public string Titles { get; set; }
}
```

With my automapper configs set as:

```
CreateMap<List<string>, string>().ConvertUsing(strings => {
            if (strings != null)
                return string.Join("\n", strings);
            return "";
        });
CreateMap<UserReport, UserModel>();
```

When trying to call from a generic method using the Automapper Ef Extensions:

```
IQueryable<TModel> modelQueryable = _reportService.GetReportBaseQuery().ProjectToQueryable<TModel>();
```

I get this error

> Missing map from System.String to System.Char. Create using Mapper.CreateMap.

`GetReportBaseQuery()` returns an `IQueryable<TReport>`, so the `UserReport` in this instance. I don't see any `char` properties, why is this coming up?

Just for testing I tried to make one:

```
CreateMap<String, Char>().ConvertUsing(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

And then it says:

> Argument types do not match

Further research shows that this works:

```
Mapper.Map<List<TReport>, List<TModel>>(_reportService.GetReportBaseQuery().ToList());
```

But I can't use that since I need it to be a queryable returned. So something is different when I try to do an EF projection, not sure what that is though. Writing a select statement from one to the other is easy enough, but that's not generic and re-usable.

Comment: Can you try this:
`CreateMap<UserReport, UserModel>().ForMember(x => x.Departments, o => o.MapFrom(s => string.Join("\n", s.Departments))).ForMember(x => x.Titles, o => o.MapFrom(s => string.Join("\n", s.Titles)));` ? I have a hypothesis, but I'm not sure whether it's right

Comment: Where does `.ProjectToQueryable<TModel>()` come from? I've installed AutoMapper.EF6 Nuget, but can't find it and seems like it is key to reproducing the error

Comment: @JakubJankowski you should be able to add `using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;` and then you should see the extension `ProjectToQueryable`
Btw I was re-creating the issue and tried your suggestion and it seems to correct the mapping, I'm wondering if Automapper is treating each string in `List<string>` as a list of characters and looking for a mapping for those

Comment: Yes In retrospect I already knew this problem: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Well, I've just found the method and reproduced your error. Indeed, the extensions treats string as collection of characters and List<string> as collection of strings, thus trying to map: `string` => `char`. Shall I create an answer from my comments?

Comment: I don't think there is an answer, it's not possible to have a string.join used in an Iqueryable. But if you'd like to write that, I will mark it as such. I got the real error once I used explicit mapping as you suggested in your first comment.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this only happens with `ProjectToQueryable` .. i.e. if I create a `List<UserReport>` and map to `UserModel` with a `Select` it's fine, but if I do `.AsQueryable().ProjectToQueryable` then I can reproduce the exception - I would've thought since the underlying type is a `List` it wouldn't make a difference

Comment: Looks like the extension's implementation could have something to do with it

Comment: @Kmoussa it's because `string.join` cannot be translated into SQL by EF. So if starting with an IQueryable<UserReport> (which GetBaseReportQuery() returned), and trying to project it to another IQueryable<UserModel> where I string.join the departments and titles property, it's not possible to do.

Comment: @DOTang but I get the same error when I have `new List<UserReport>(){/*..*/}.AsQueryable().ProjectToQueryable` which shouldn't be translating anything to SQL as the underlying type of the queryable is a list

Comment: Actually, to be sure I changed the mapping to `CreateMap<List<string>, string>().ConvertUsing(strings => "" );` and the exception still happens - I'd be inclined to a bug in `ProjectToQueryable` rather than some issue with generating SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to explicitly set mapping for the `Departments` and `Titles` fields:

```
CreateMap<UserReport, UserModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Departments, o => o.MapFrom(s => string.Join("\n", s.Departments)))
    .ForMember(x => x.Titles, o => o.MapFrom(s => string.Join("\n", s.Titles)));
```

**But**, this does not explain, why this situation occurs.
As DOTang pointed out:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The AutoMapper extension seems to try to map the following thing:

```
IEnumerable<string> => IEnumerable<char>
```