# AutoMapper - string.Join causing missing mapping from char to string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, breeze

I have a DTO that I wish to return a comma delimited string "xxx, ddd, ccc" in the FirstName property.  I setup the property as an ICollection because if I just use the string declaration I get the following error:

Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
//DTO
public class fooGridViewModel
{
   public virtual ICollection<string> FirstName { get; set; }
}


//Auto Mapper Initialize / Config
cfg.CreateMap<fooSource, fooGridViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.foo,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(model => string.Join(",", model.Names
                   .Where(we => we.LastName == "Smith")
                   .Select(o => o.FirstName)))
```

When this code executes I am now receiving an error in the conversion that states: **Additional Information Missing map from System.Char to System.String.  Create using Mapper.CreateMap.**

```
//Conversion
public static IQueryable<fooGridViewModel> ToGridViewModels(this IQueryable<fooSource> source)
{
    return source.ProjectTo<fooGridViewModel>();
}

//Controller
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 10)]
public IQueryable<fooGridViewModel> fooGridViewModels()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.fooSources.ToGridViewModels();
}
```

I have researched potential fixes [AutoMapper: Collection to Single string Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816068/automapper-collection-to-single-string-property) but do not understand how/where to place the AsEnumerable method.

As well as [Automapper says Missing map from System.String to System.Char? But I see no Char property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006595/automapper-says-missing-map-from-system-string-to-system-char-but-i-see-no-char) for explicitly mapping the properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you are mapping from an IQueryable object. Any Linq functions you call on that object will be the IQueryable versions, treated as an addition to the SQL query which is being built up.

When that query is executed, you get errors because most C# functions such as `string.Join` cannot be converted into SQL by the adapter.

In short

- IQueryable objects build up a SQL query string, without executing it
- When the query is enumerated, the SQL is sent to the database, and the results are loaded
- Only then can you call whatever C# function you wish.

So execute the query in a controlled manner, **before** allowing general-purpose C# functions to be used with it.

```
  //Conversion
  public static List<fooGridViewModel> ToGridViewModels(this IQueryable<fooSource> source)
  {
      List<fooSource> results = source.ToList();    // send SQL to database, load results

      return results.ProjectTo<fooGridViewModel>(); // convert results to view-model

  }
```

Comment: When I call source.ToList() it will basically do a Select All on fooSource which  will bring back 300k+ rows right?  Then the automapper will do it's filtering on that.   That seems expensive to do, that I need to filter on the SQL Query.    

I was trying to get the field comma delimited so i can do a entityQuery filter and just say "FirstName", "contains", "Dan"  .. but if i bring it back as a List<string>  do you know if I can change my entity query to do like a "FirstName", "in", "Dan"  ?  My first attempt got "The 'in' operator requires that its right hand argument be an array"

Comment: So do the filtering at the IQueryable stage, before .ToList(). No need to use AutoMapper for filtering.